# R Kmeans and for loop

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop

Hi Everyone i am trying our this code but somehow it isn't working.

```
   wss = NULL
   bss = NULL
   s_kmeans <- function(fname)
     {
       dataset <- read.csv(file=fname,header = TRUE, sep = ",")
       for(i in 1:10)
          {
            results <- kmeans(dataset,i)
            wss[i] <- results$tot.withinss
            bss[i] <- results$betweenss
          }
     }
```

What I am trying to do is take two arrays wss and bss. Run kmeans multiple times using for loop and in each loop store values to total withinss and betweenss in wss and bss respectively. But when I run the code I only get NULL stored in wss and bss. Anyone can please suggest a better way to do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that you are running this code in a function which does not have a return value?  And also are you sure your input file is correct?

Comment: I am sorry  I didn't look at it before. Now I have modified the code: s_kmeans <- function(fname)
  {
    wss = NULL
    dataset <- read.csv(file=fname,header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    for(i in 1:10)
    {
      results <- kmeans(dataset,i)
      wss[i] <- results$tot.withinss
    }
    
    return(wss) 
  } Now I am getting output but when I try to access wss outside function it says "Error: object 'wss' not found".

Comment: Put the code into your question, not a comment.

Comment: Please, provide and examle of your `dataset`

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks to @TimBiegeleisen I have realized my mistake. I should use this function to plot my results not to return some array and then use that array to plot a graph. Now I am plotting graph inside function which is doing my job well.